# Compiz, "put" plugin, prev/next order

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, compiz

I have triple-head, each 90-degrees rotated monitor layout:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4920 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected 1080x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 475mm x 267mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1080x1920+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1080x1920+3840+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 475mm x 267mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And have `super-shift-left` and `super-shift-right` shortcuts set to move windows across the monitors:

[image]

For some reason, the behavior is exactly the opposite to what I expect to see, i.e. `super-shift-left` moves window to the right of its current monitor position, and `super-shift-right` does the reverse. It's amusing enough that it used to work with the same set of monitors and on the same installation of Ubuntu 16.04. I just happen to disassemble/assemble my workstation moving from one room to another.

Comment: I bet you were using usb video cards and hooked them up backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the wrong order of the outputs in Compiz config. For some reason I had layout shown on the picture below

[image]

while the correct left to right layout should look like

[image]

After fixing and logging out and in everything started to work as expected.